# wxPython - How to sort ListCtrl column items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to create an CheckListCtrl where you could sort all the Data in an column by clicking on its header.

In the basic example of my code i will post below i setup "rows" as a List of Tuples because in my final version the ListCtrl will show the result of an SQLite Query.

**The problem i have with my code so far:**

I used `self.itemDataMap = rows` wrong i think, i get this error message if i try to sort: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. So how do i use it with an List of Tuples and not with an Dictionary?

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

APPNAME='Sortable Ultimate List Ctrl'
APPVERSION='1.0'
MAIN_WIDTH=300
MAIN_HEIGHT=300

class TestUltimateListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS, size=(MAIN_WIDTH,MAIN_HEIGHT))

        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, -1, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]

        index = 0
        for data in rows:
            pos=self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, data[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, data[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, data[3])

            self.list_ctrl.SetItemData(index, rows[index])

            index += 1

        self.itemDataMap = rows

        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColClick, self.list_ctrl)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.list_ctrl

    def OnColClick(self, event):
        pass

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,wx.ID_ANY,'%s v%s' % (APPNAME,APPVERSION),size=(MAIN_WIDTH,MAIN_HEIGHT),style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        panel = TestUltimateListCtrlPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let me quote the documentation of [`wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.ColumnSorterMixin`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.ColumnSorterMixin.html):

> The combined class must have an attribute named itemDataMap that is a dictionary mapping the data values to a sequence of objects representing the values in each column. These values are compared in the column sorter to determine sort order.

That's hardly understandable.

What it means is, that `.itemDataMap` hs to be a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), where the key of each entry are the data of a row. The value is a list:

```py
self.itemDataMap = {}
for rowIndex, data in enumerate(rows):
    self.itemDataMap[data] = []
```

Each element of the immer list is associated to a column and is used to sort the elements of a column. If the rows should be sorted in alphabetic order dependent of the values of a column, then the value which is associated to the column index (in the dictionary of a row) can be the value of the filed:

```py
self.itemDataMap[data] = []
for coldata in data:
    self.itemDataMap[data] += coldata
```

Since the rows are already organised in a list, the rows can be use directly:

```py
self.itemDataMap[data] = data
```

The same can be achieved by

```py
self.itemDataMap = {data : data for data in rows}
```

Note, the keys of `.itemDataMap` have to correspond to the data of a row, which is set by `SetItemData()`.

Since the data of a row are organised in a list

When the list should be sorted by the values of specific column index `col`, then all then elements in `.itemDataMap` which are associated to `col` are listed and the list is sorted by this elements. You can imagine this like:

```py
col = ... # integral index of the column 
sorted( [values[col] for values in self.itemDataMap.values()] )
```

---

Further note, the number of columns is 4:

<s>`listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)`</s>
`listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 4)`

---

Class `TestUltimateListCtrlPanel`:

[image]

```py
class TestUltimateListCtrlPanel(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS, size=(MAIN_WIDTH,MAIN_HEIGHT))

        self.list_ctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, -1, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]

        for rowIndex, data in enumerate(rows):
            for colIndex, coldata in enumerate(data):
                if colIndex == 0:
                    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(rowIndex, coldata)
                else:
                    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(rowIndex, colIndex, coldata)
            self.list_ctrl.SetItemData(rowIndex, data)

        self.itemDataMap = {data : data for data in rows} 

        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 4)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.OnColClick, self.list_ctrl)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.list_ctrl

    def OnColClick(self, event):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that very newbe friendly answere! I have know the solution AND the understanding of how it works. Perfect!